# Windows 10 GPT error UEFI vs. MBR

Tags: uefi, windows-installation, gpt

A) Inserted Win10 installation USB, booted to legacy BIOS, deleted primary partition > ERROR ... unable to install to GPT formatted drive. 
B) Tried switching to UEFI boot mode > changed boot order to USB first but unable to boot to Win10 installation because system wants to repair the deleted drive ... help please

Answer (score 0):

I removed the hard drive and plugged it into my working PC - with a usb to 2.5 sata adapter.

Start > Run > cmd > right click "As Administrator" ...

> diskpart (enter)...
>   list disk (enter) ...
>   select disk #__ (Verify you have the right one! Look at the size and MAKE SURE you have the right DISK!) ... (enter) ... 
>   clean (enter) ...
>   create part pri (enter) ...
>   select part 1 (enter) ...
>   format fs=ntfs quick

Put the hard drive back into the original PC and was able to successfully install Windows 10